# DDD - Service or Handler in Subscriber?

Tags: service, domain-driven-design

I'm having a DDD project, and I don't know if is better to use Handler or Service directly in Subscribers.

Let me clarify; Assiming that

- Command object must receive in input only primitive type
- Handler receive command and transform primitive data in domain model

My question is: if I raise a domain event, the subscriber, should run a service or another command handler?

Let me do an example:

```
class CommandOne{    
    public function __construct(string $stuff){
        $this->stuff = $stuff;
    }
    public function getStuff(){
        return $this->stuff;
    }
}

// Handler, called from a ControllerAction
class HandlerCommandOne{

    public function __construct(StuffRepository $stuffRepository, 
                                SomeService $service){
        $this->service = $service;
        $this->stuffRepository = $stuffRepository;
    }

    public function handle(CommandOne $command){

        $stuff = $command->getStuff();
        $stuffModel = $this->stuffRepository->find($stuff);

        //Some Business Logic
        $this->service->doBusinessActivity();
        $this->anotherService->doAnotherBusinessActivity();

        // If I want that subscriber will use  Service , I inject a model in event constructor
        $this->dispatcher->dispatch(StuffEvent::NAME,new StuffEvent($stuffModel));

        // If I want that subscriber will use a CommandHandler , I inject primitives in event constructor
        $this->dispatcher->dispatch(StuffEvent::NAME,new StuffEvent($stuffModel->getId(),$stuffModel->getName()));
    }
}


class SomeSubscriberWithHandler{    
    public function __construct(CommandHandler $handler) {
        $this->handler = $handler;        
    }
    public function OnStuffEvent($event){                    
        $command = new SomeOtherCommand($event->getId(), $event->getName());
        $this->handler->handle($command); // Handle will handle logic calling other services ...
    }
}

class SomeSubscriberWithService{        
    public function __construct(Service $service) {
        $this->service = $service;
    }
    public function OnStuffEvent($event){
        $model = $event->getModel();
        $this->service->doLogic($model);
    }
}
```

I see pro and cons; I know that, in DDD, is better su create event with PRIMITIVES data, cause event can be catched outside the bounded context, where your model can have no meaning.

But if I use primitive, I have to call repository every time I need information from the entity ....

As an example, a subscriber must notify that a new model has been created, sending  emails; would you create handler in subscribers, or services directly?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Given we implement the communication between bounded contexts (BCs) with a message queue (MQ), the upstream BC would publish a domain event by translating it into a message that will be send to the MQ.

On the other side, the subscriber in the downstream BC would be a listener that would translate the message received from the MQ into a command, and run the command handler.

The listener is infraestructure, since it deals with technology (MQ). It is outside the application, takes a message and calls an application service (or command handler).

This is how it is done in the examples from the Red Book (Implementing Domain Driven Design). You can take a look to them at https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples